# Armadillo: efficient matrix allocation on the heap

Tags: heap-memory, armadillo

I'm using Armadillo to manipulate large matrices in C++ read from a CSV-file.

```
mat X;
X.load("myfile.csv",csv_ascii);
colvec x1 = X(span::all,0);
colvec x2 = X(span::all,1);
//etc.
```

So x1,...,xk (for `k=20` say) are the columns of X. X will typically have rows ranging from 2000 to 16000. My question is:

**How can I allocate (and subsequently deallocate) X onto the heap (free store)?**

[This section](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat) of Armadillo docs explains auxiliary memory allocation of a mat. Is this the same as heap allocation? It requires prior knowledge of matrix dimensions, which I won't know until X is read from csv:

```
mat(aux_mem*, n_rows, n_cols, copy_aux_mem = true, strict = true)
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. (I'm using g++-4.2.1; my current program runs fine locally on my Macbook Pro, but when I run it on my university's computing cluster (Linux g++-4.1.2), I run into a segmentation fault. The program is too large to post).

**Edit:** I ended up doing this:

```
arma::u32 Z_rows = 10000;
arma::u32 Z_cols = 20;
double* aux_mem = new double[Z_rows*Z_cols];
mat Z(aux_mem,Z_rows,Z_cols,false,true);
Z = randn(Z_rows, Z_cols);
```

which first allocates memory on the heap and then tells the matrix Z to use it.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the source code, Armadillo already allocates large matrices on the heap.

To reduce the amount of memory required, you may want to use *fmat* instead of *mat*. This will come with the trade-off of reduced precision.

*fmat* uses float, while *mat* uses double: see http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat.

It's also possible that the system administrator of the linux computing cluster has enabled limits on it (eg. each user can allocate only upto a certain amount of maximum memory).  For example, see http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/ulimit.htm.

Comment: Does Armadillo deallocate the memory too, or should this be done by the user?

Comment: @MikelUrkia - Any properly written C++ library will automatically deallocate the memory used by its objects. What makes you think that it needs to be done manually? C++ is not C.

Comment: I am pretty new in C and C++, and I appreciate the time you took to answer my question. As mentioned in another question of mine, if Armadillo takes care of memory management, it will ease my work considerably.