# Armadillo: deallocate memory

Tags: c++, memory-management, matrix, armadillo

I am working with *Armadillo 4.320.2* and I would like to know if the library itself does take care of memory allocation and deallocation. Having a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315337/armadillo-efficient-matrix-allocation-on-the-heap) question, an answer determines that *Armadillo* does indeed allocate the memory for matrices, but it does not mention anything about memory  deallocation.

If *Armadillo* does not free the memory occupied by matrices, how could I do it manually?

Comment: Armadillo is a well written C++ library, where the matrix objects are properly destroyed (ie. memory is deallocated when the matrix objects go out of scope). Have a look at the source code: file include/armadillo_bits/Mat_meat.hpp, the destructor function ~Mat()

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there is no actual problem

Comment: So the answer would be that indeed, Armadillo does take care of memory management in all cases? If so, I am glad to know it, it will ease my work considerably. Thanks for the source code suggestion, @mtall

Comment: We are using Armadillo in a very complex mathematical model and it will be run 24/7. So far, even after days of testing there is no memory increase. I am pretty sure the authors have checked their code many times if all "new" statements will be concluded by a "delete" somewhere. In general this is what to expect from a library, you can use it and do not think about internals